# reactjs action creators pass an array

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

How to pass set of arrays in an object from a react component for a post request: This should be the structure of my request object:

```
    {
  "test": [
    "abc"
  ],
  "test2": [
    "def"
  ],
  "test3": [
    "sds"
  ],
  "name": "sam"
}
```

getting error when I do:

React Component:

```
this.props.actioncreatorCall(
      someurl,
      ["abc"],
      ["def"],
      ["sasd"],
      "sam"
    );
```

Action creator:

```
export function apiCAll(someurl,{test, test2, test3, name}) {
return function dispatchUser(dispatch) {
axios.post((url),{test,
  test2,
  test3,
  name},{ }, 
 ).then((response) => {
    dispatch({
      type: DATA_POST,
      payload: response.data,
    });
    browserHistory.push('/NEXTPAGE');
  })
  .catch(() => {
     //SOME ERROR
  });
```

};
}

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in the second param as an object:

```
this.props.actioncreatorCall(someurl,{
    test: ["abc"],
    test2: ["def"],
    test3: ["sasd"],
    name: "sam"
});
```

And you action creator needs to accept an object as the second param:

```
export function actioncreatorCall(someurl, test = {}) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Chase. Really appreciate it.